# How to read files inside Directory and store in memory in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a Directory structure as following:

```
Folder Structure 
        Config—folder

                10001—folder
                        20001—folder
                            20001.properties
                   10001.properties                         

                App.json
                Config.properties
```

here Config,10001,20001 are folders.
i want a logic to be implemented as, if i give Config as a Root folder, then my code should scan and generate output as following:

```
Config.Config.properties : {
here it should have the config.propertis values
}

Config.App.json : {
    here it should have the config.propertis values
}

Config.10001.10001.properties : {
here it should have the 10001.propertis values
}

Config.10001.20001.20001.properties : {
here it should have the 20001.propertis values
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [this](https://github.com/vancarney/require_tree) package it'll look like that:

```
require('require_tree').require_tree('./Config', {preserve_filenames: true})
```

PS: please don't write your config files in json :)